# How can I initialize a SparseVector in Eigen

Tags: c++, eigen

How can I initialize a SparseVector in Eigen ? The following code:

```
#define EIGEN_YES_I_KNOW_SPARSE_MODULE_IS_NOT_STABLE_YET
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
using namespace Eigen;
SparseVector<float> vec(3);
main()
{
  vec(0)=1.0;
}
```

gives me the following error

> error: call of an object of a class type without appropriate operator() or conversion functions to pointer-to-function type
>     vec(0)=1.0;

by the way, vec[0]=1.0  doesn't work either.

Comment: Never heard of Eigen but cursory peek at the documentation I noticed `coeffRef`, did you try `vec.coeffRef(0) = 1.0` also?

Comment: Thanks a lot. This is indeed the way of insertion in SparseVector.

Comment: All right, I'll answer it thusly then...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the documentation I noticed `Scalar& coeffRef(Index i)`, and it says:

*Returns a reference to the coefficient value at given index i.  This operation involes a log(rho*size) binary search. If the coefficient does not exist yet, then a sorted insertion into a sequential buffer is performed.  (This insertion might be very costly if the number of nonzeros above i is large.)*

So the following should work:

```
#define EIGEN_YES_I_KNOW_SPARSE_MODULE_IS_NOT_STABLE_YET
#include <Eigen/Sparse>
using namespace Eigen;
SparseVector<float> vec(3);
main()
{
    vec.coeffRef(0)=1.0;
}
```

Not sure why they did it that way instead of using array overloading.  Perhaps when it becomes IS_STABLE then they'll do it in a more typical C++ way?

Comment: I think they wanted make users aware of a potentially costly op.

Comment: Yeah but this is just incorrect syntax.  You don't generally _assign_ to the return value of a function call.

Comment: I agree with bobobobo that the current interface is just confusing. I found this website because the obvious syntax didn't work. That is a sign that the interface is a bit obtuse (not to mention verbose).