# How to efficiently initialize a SparseVector in Eigen

Tags: c++, sparse-matrix, eigen

In the Eigen docs for filling a sparse matrix it is recommended to use the [triplet filling method](https://eigen.tuxfamily.org/dox/group__TutorialSparse.html#title3) as it can be much more efficient than making calls to `coeffRef`, which involves a binary search.

For filling `SparseVectors` however, there is no clear recommendation on how to do it efficiently.

The suggested method in this [SO answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7518234/209882) uses `coeffRef` which means that a binary search is performed for every insertion.

Is there a recommended, efficient way to build sparse vectors? Should I try to create a single row `SparseMatrix` and then store that as a `SparseVector`?

My use case is reading in LibSVM files, in which there can be millions of very sparse features and billions of data points. I'm currently representing these as an `std::vector<Eigen::SparseVector>`. Perhaps I should just use `SparseMatrix` instead?

Edit: One thing I've tried is this:

```
// for every data point in a batch do the following:

Eigen::SparseMatrix<float> features(1, num_features);
// copy the data over
typedef Eigen::Triplet<float> T;
std::vector<T> tripletList;
for (int j = 0; j < num_batch_instances; ++j) {
  for (size_t i = batch.offset[j]; i < batch.offset[j + 1]; ++i) {
    uint32_t index = batch.index[i];
    float fvalue = batch.value;
    if (index < num_features) {
      tripletList.emplace_back(T(0, index, fvalue));
    }
  }
  features.setFromTriplets(tripletList.begin(), tripletList.end());
  samples->emplace_back(Eigen::SparseVector<float>(features));
}
```

This creates a `SparseMatrix` using the triplet list approach, then creates a `SparseVector` from that object. In my experiments with ~1.4M features and very high sparsity this is *2 orders of magnitude* slower than using `SparseVector` and `coeffRef`, which I definitely did not expect.

Comment: If they are already sorted, just properly reserve space and then call `vec.insertBack(i) = ...;`

Comment: Hello @ggael, by sorted here you mean if my data file has the features in increasing index? LibSVM files _should_ have a guarantee like that.

Comment: Hello @ggael, I tried this approach and I'm running into an unexpected error: `include/Eigen/src/SparseCore/SparseVector.h:184: Eigen::SparseVector<_Scalar, _Flags, _StorageIndex>::Scalar& Eigen::SparseVector<_Scalar, 
_Flags, _StorageIndex>::insert(Eigen::Index) [with _Scalar = float; int _Options = 0; _StorageIndex = int; Eigen::SparseVector<_Scalar, _Flags, _StorageIndex>::Scalar = float; 
Eigen::Index = long int]: Assertion 'i>=0 && i<m_size' failed.`

This is unexpected because `insertBack`  never calls insert, which is where this error originates. Any idea what might be the cause?